# Text extraction using python

Tags: python

I am trying to print all the below content  of text file once a keyword is encountered using python.

Below is the code which I have written.

```
Filepath="D:/xyz.txt"
with open(filepath)as fp
 for line in fp:
  for path in line.split(" ")
        if "error" or "exception "  in fp:#It #should print all the content after error or #exception in line
           print line
```

Comment: Python keywords should be all lowercase, `with`, `for`, `print`, etc.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question so I've made a guess as to what the problem is, assuming the glaring syntax errors are just a copy-paste issue. If that's not the problem, give an actual [mcve]. And please make more effort with the formatting next time.

Comment: I will keep next time in mind